# Remote desktop show screen

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-access

Is it possible to show the screen on the remote computer when using remote desktop?
(Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008)
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You'll have to use something else like VNC in order to do that. There is a way to take over the console session by passing the /admin switch to mstsc. This will still lock the local screen though.

Comment: Is there an alternative to VNC? It seems that their free version isn't compatible with windows7/server 2008. Thanks.

Comment: @Rauland - RealVNC Enterprise is supported on WS2008R2